# extending a component causes ui:inputDate to break

Tags: lightning

All my fields is showing up correctly until i'm extending another component.
 see the example below :

[image]

When i remove then extension part, here is how my component render :

[image]

Forget about the modal header and footer. This is the part created by my extension. But what I actually can't undestanding is why when using extension, this break variables initialisation and aura ui ? It should not have been the case isn't it. The UI:inputDate seems reset.

Here is my extension component code :

```
<aura:component extensible="true" abstract="true">
<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<!-- **************** GLOBAL/SHARED ATTRIBUTES *****************-->
<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<aura:attribute name="showModal" type="boolean" default="false" description="Show/hide the modal window"/>
<aura:attribute name="refresh" type="boolean" default="false" description="Tell the caller that we have finish. If refresh = true then refresh"/>
<aura:attribute name="overrideMargin" type="string" default="margin: -15px -15px -15px -15px" description="Tell the caller that we have finish. If refresh = true then refresh"/>
<aura:attribute name="useModal" type="boolean" default="true" description="If set to true, then the black window + close button will display"/>
<aura:attribute name="height" type="integer" default="250" description="The max height of the body. Note that when using from a component, the default should be 250"/>
<aura:attribute name="modalHeader" type="string" default="Modal header" description="The modal title header"/>
<!-- save button attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="disableSave" type="boolean" default="false" description="This variable allow disabling the save button. For example when saving"/>
<aura:attribute name="saveButtonText" type="string" default="{!$Label.c.VFP02Sauvegarder}" description="This variable allow overriding the save button text"/>
<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<!-- **************** EVENTS REGISTRATION *****************-->
<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<aura:registerEvent name="triggerSave" type="c:LE_ModalExtension"/>

<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<!-- ****************    SHOW COMPLETE MODAL      *****************-->
<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<div role="dialog" class="{!v.showModal &amp;&amp; v.useModal? 'slds-modal slds-fade-in-open': 'slds-hide'}">
      <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header slds-modal__header--empty">
          <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.handleClose}">
                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" />
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div aura:id="xid-body" class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">                              
            <div style="{!v.overrideMargin}">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">                    
                    <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">{!v.modalHeader}</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- height should be height of component defined - 118 -->
                <div class="slds-grid" style="{! 'max-height:' + (v.height - 118) + 'px;overflow-y:auto'}">             
                    {!v.body}
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.handleClose}">{!$Label.c.GLO_Annuler}</button>
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.handleSave}">{!v.saveButtonText}</button>
                </div>                      
             </div>                     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="{!v.showModal &amp;&amp; v.useModal? 'slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open': 'slds-hide'}"></div>

<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<!-- ************   SHOW ONLY HEADER AND BUTTON  *****************-->
<!-- ************************************************************* -->
<div class="{!v.useModal ? 'slds-hide' : 'slds-show'}">
    <div style="{!v.overrideMargin}">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">                    
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">{!v.modalHeader}</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- height should be height of component defined - 118 -->
        <div class="slds-grid" style="{! 'height:' + (v.height - 118) + 'px;overflow-y:auto'}">             
            {!v.body}
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.handleClose}">{!$Label.c.GLO_Annuler}</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.handleSave}">{!v.saveButtonText}</button>
        </div>                  
     </div> 

   </div> 
   </aura:component>
```

I'm not overiding any CSS here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to solve it. Bizarrely it was just something to do with the consitional rendering using the slds-hide. I replace the conditonal using aura:if. It works like a charm. ooof :)